# Explain compiled code structure and static allocation

Tags: c, compilation

I was looking at the difference in C between `char* c = "thomas";` and `char c[] = "thomas";`. I saw questions about this here and while trying to understand the answers I wanted to check that I was right by looking at the assembly. And a few questions were born.

Here is what I thought :

1. `char* c = ...` : the characters are allocated somewhere on the static memory (read only from the program's perspective), alongside with the code. That's why it should be marked `const`. The string can be printed but not modified.
2. `char c[] = ...` : Same as 1. except that when a function is called, the characters are copied in an array on the stack, so it can be modified etc etc.

I wanted to check this so I made this C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(){
  char c [] = "thomas blabljbflkjbsdflkjbds";
  printf("%s\n", c);
}
```

Looking at the generated assembly :

```
   0x400564 <main>:    push   rbp
   0x400565 <main+1>:    mov    rbp,rsp
   0x400568 <main+4>:    sub    rsp,0x30
   0x40056c <main+8>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x400575 <main+17>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x400579 <main+21>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x40057b <main+23>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x30],0x6978616d
   0x400582 <main+30>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x2c],0x6220656d
   0x400589 <main+37>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],0x6c62616c
   0x400590 <main+44>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24],0x6c66626a
   0x400597 <main+51>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],0x73626a6b
   0x40059e <main+58>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c],0x6b6c6664
   0x4005a5 <main+65>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x7364626a
   0x4005ac <main+72>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x14],0x0
   0x4005b0 <main+76>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x30]
   0x4005b4 <main+80>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x4005b7 <main+83>:    call   0x400450 <puts@plt>
   0x4005bc <main+88>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x4005c0 <main+92>:    xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x4005c9 <main+101>:    je     0x4005d0 <main+108>
```

So characters are copied into the stack, which is what I thought.

*Questions :*

1. The characters are stored by bytes at addresses `0x6978616d, 0x6220656d` and so on. Why aren't they allocated contiguously in an array ? Simple optimization of the compiler ?
2. 1. explains why `char*` doesn't behave like an array and why `c[10]` isn't the 11th character of the string. *However* it doesn't explain why

   char* c = "thomas blabljbflkjbsdflkjbds";
   printf("%s\n", c);

works. (Note the [] -> *). I guess that `printf` reads characters by characters until it reaches a 0, so knowing just c `(i.e &c[0])` how does it access `c[10]` ? (because of the non contiguous and the fact that this time chars are not copied to an array on the stack)

I hope that I am clear, I can reformulate if you ask/don't understand a point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: `0x6978616d`, `0x6220656d` are not addresses, it is the data in your string. When converted to from hex to ascii, `0x6978616d` = `moht`, `0x6220656d` = `b sa`.

2: When used in a function call, arrays decay into pointers. So `printf` will receive a pointer to char regardless of if `c` is an array or a pointer.

Comment: I will add for 2. the string is actually represented as a static array somewhere near the code, I see it when I look at the disassembly for `char*c = "lksdlkfjsd"; printf("%s\n", c);`. So it is not as if the array was fragmented and the second question doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler may actually choose to compile character array initialisation as a copy from read-only storage, but as Klas suggests, that is not happening in your example.

Here is an example of code for which that does happen (using gcc). It may be illuminating to change the definition of `STR` to strings of various lengths and look at the difference in assembly output.

```
/* 99 characters */
#define STR "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"

void observe(const char *);

void test1() {
    char *str = STR;
    observe(str);
}
void test2() {
    char str[] = STR;
    observe(str);
}
```

And the assembly:

```
    .section    .rodata.str1.4,"aMS",@progbits,1
    .align 4
.LC0:
    .string "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"

    .text
test2:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    $25, %ecx
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $136, %esp
    movl    %esi, -8(%ebp)
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    %edi, -4(%ebp)
    leal    -108(%ebp), %edi
    rep movsl
    leal    -108(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    observe
    movl    -8(%ebp), %esi
    movl    -4(%ebp), %edi
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret

test1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    observe
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: I don't read assembly that well, can you explain in English the difference that you see ? Thanks

Comment: The interesting bits are `movl $.LC0, %esi`, which loads the address of read-only storage, and `rep movsl`, a block copy instruction. Compare that to the assembly in your post: there is no copy at all, just stores of immediate values into the stack.

Comment: very interesting, I start to see what you mean (apart from block copy : copy what block to where ?). Why do you think the compiler reserves 0x108 bytes or so on test2 stack if it doesn't copy the chars there ?

Comment: I guess I didn't make that clear enough: the assembly for `test2` _does_ copy the string onto the stack, from read-only memory (that's `.LC0`).

Comment: Ok, I thought something else : that when using only f(const char*) the compiler would think that there is no need to copy and would give directly the pointer to the static readonly memory. Too bad this is not happening but I see your point now too : bytes not passed in code but in static memory if it is used in different places and the string is big to save some code